# Why do I get a 404 for this Razor Page Ajax call?

Tags: http, razor, razor-pages

I am calling an Ajax function in the `Register` page, using the following client code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/Register?handler=GeneratePassword",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        $("#genPwd").val(response.Password);
    },
    failure: function (response) {
        alert(response);
    }
});
```

And the action in the Page Model looks like this:

```
public JsonResult OnGetGeneratePassword()
{
    var pwd = _passwordService.GeneratePassword(_passwordOptions);
    return new JsonResult(new { Ok = true, Password = pwd });
}
```

According to what I read about Razor Page Ajax calls, this should work, so why the 404?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using an IActionResult instead of a JsonResult

```
public IActionResult OnGetGeneratePassword()
{
    var pwd = _passwordService.GeneratePassword(_passwordOptions);
    return new JsonResult(new { Ok = true, Password = pwd });
}
```

Also another thing you can try is removing the / at the beginning of the ajax url like so:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "Register?handler=GeneratePassword",
```

Comment: Just fixing the URL worked, thanks, but did both changes. All my other actions return `IActionResult` anyway.

Comment: @ProfK You should be specific about the return type of your handler methods. You typically only return `IActionResult` if you don't know the return type of the handler, such as when you might return a `RedirectToPageResult` if a form submission is successful, or a `PageResult` if the `ModelState` is not valid. The return type has nothing to do with the issue that you reported, as you have found.